# Dynamic supervisor starts itself as a child supervisor

Tags: process, erlang, erlang-supervisor

I need a supervisor who can start two kinds of childen.

the first is a supervisor child, like the supervisor, 
can i start a child with the same module like the supervisor?

For Example:

```
-module(test_sup).
-behaviour(supervisor).

-export([start_link/0]).
-export([init/1]).

start_link() ->
     supervisor:start_link({local,?MODULE}, ?MODULE, []).

init(_Args) ->
        RestartStrategy = {one_for_one, 10, 60},
        {ok, {RestartStrategy, 

        [{sup,
        {sup, start_link, []},
        permanent, infinity, supervisor, [sup]},

  ]}}.
```

in the supervisor module i init a child with the same module, is it possible?

the second kind of child is a normal worker, with a own module, this is not the problem.
But can i starts dynamic this two different kinds in the supervisor module?

Comment: If a supervisor spawns itself, than you get an infinite tree of supervisors, right? Probably crashes the app when running out of memory. Seems rather useless. What do you want to accomplish?

Comment: i want to make a index of a directory, for example i start the supervisor in a dir and for each subfolder i want to start a new supervisor process. And the supervisor of each folder starts a child process to index the files of the folder. it is a exercise from an course

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your comment, you said that you want to start up a process for every subfolder you run into. OTP created the [`simple_one_for_one`](http://www.erlang.org/doc/design_principles/sup_princ.html#id72445)  supervisor for that.

In the start_link of the worker process, you can supply the directory path you want the process to index as the argument.

You can look at my [full text search engine](http://blog.equanimity.nl/blog/2011/10/07/a-basic-full-text-search-server-in-erlang/#otp_tree) tutorial for a working example of a `simple_one_for_one` supervisor.

Comment: But then i have one supervisor who control the worker of all folders, or?
But i need a supervisor tree like the directory tree.
For example, I start the supervisor in the folder "home" with two subfolder "mary" and "joe",
so i need two child-supervisor for this subfolder.
And each of the supervisors must start a worker for the files.

Comment: and the supervisor-child of the subfolder "mary" for example must start other supervisor-child for the subfolder in "mary". and so on...

Comment: @user2513102 I understand this is an assignment you have to do, but I think creating a supervisor tree like that doesn't teach one about a proper understanding of OTP principles. And that should be the ultimate goal right?

Answer (score 0):

The suggestion of Ward is really the good one. You can have a look at this page: [LearYousomeErlang : the count of application](http://learnyousomeerlang.com/the-count-of-applications), it has a complete example of the pattern you should use